# How to remove RoleAssignments from SPListItem/SPFolder correctly in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, document-library, 2016, security, item-level-permissions

In the library, I have ParentFolder which contains SubFolder. I have broken role inheritance in both ParentFolder and SubFolder (via a web interface).

But when I remove role assignment for the user in ParentFolder with PowerShell script it disappears in Subfolder too. I don't understand why it disappears if I have broken role inheritance. 
And how to prevent it? How could I delete role assignment for the user in ParentFolder, but save it in a subfolder?

Here is the code:

```
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
$object.RoleAssignments.Remove($user)
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
$object.SystemUpdate($true)
```

I have SharePoint 2016

Comment: Have you broken the inheritance on subfolders as well? Or subfolders are inheriting permissions from Parent Folder?

Comment: Yes, I did. I broke role inheritance in SubFolder too.

Comment: You need minimum read permissions

Comment: I'm site administrator. I can delete permission. But if I delete user permission in Parent it deletes in SubFolder as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior for SharePoint.  If User A is in Group 1, and you break inheritance  on the folder and sub folder, then remove User A from Group 1 at the Folder level, it will also remove User A from Group 1 at the sub folder level.  The way around this is the break inheritance then create a new group at the sub folder level and then assign the users to the new group.

Comment: Yes, but in that case Limited Access permissions will be created in all upper folders for this goup. And this is not good for me, because my task is to delete all Limited Access permissions. (I know how it will effect on permissions)